# Object [object Object] has no method 'slides'

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am using the enqueue function to link two javascript files. I get this error  `Object [object Object] has no method 'slides'`
I checked and I am not loading jquery more than once. The code that is causing this error is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/loading.gif',
        play: 5000, 
        pause: 2500, 
        hoverPause: true                 
    }); 
 });
```

[Example Link](http://wpcasa.adrianeufracio.com/?golf_locations=punta-cana)

Comment: It means there is no `slides` method in your javascript.  `$('#slides').slides`. Make sure the library has enqueue.

Comment: It has enqueued. Checked using the network tab and it is pulling the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `slidesjs` instead of `slides` in your code. Update your JS from:

`$('#slides').slides({`

to

`$('#slides').slidesjs({`

if you're using [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/). BTW, I found an error that you shouldn't use PHP tag in your JS code.

Comment: Could you mark this question as answered? Thanks!